# How apply padding in HTML without increasing the div size?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply some padding in a div, but when the padding property is applied, the div size increases because the padding size is added to the div.

```
<div id="someDiv">
    someContent
</div>

#someDiv{
    padding: 1em;
}
```

There is some way to apply the padding without increasing the div size? I have one solution that includes adding another with the content div inside the #someDiv and applying margin to it, but I don't know if this is the best solution.

Something like this:

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <div idi="anotherDiv">
        someContent
    </div>
</div>

#anotherDiv{
    margin: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an inner div is, more or less, a good solution. There's the `box-sizing` property, but it lacks support.

Here's an article on the subject:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

And here's a polyfill (patch) for older IE versions -- although I'm not sure how it affects performance; I'd recommend using it carefully.

https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill

Comment: Arrived here from the future in 2020, I can report that box-sizing is well supported now: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing and works great for this precise problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
div { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Although this is isn't supported in certain versions of IE!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `<div>` with an auto-width, i.e. which will automatically grow to the width of its parent element, adding padding will not increase the width. It will increase the height, which is of course inevitable. The width will only increase if you have set a fixed width for the element, the total width will then be `width + padding`. In that case, subtract the added padding from the set width.

Comment: I understand this solution, but I can't apply it. I'm using Bootstrap, so it uses fixed width (span1, span2, etc.) and is not possible to change the width in a simple clear way.

Comment: That's an unfortunate problem. You can always *override* the default CSS though by resetting `width` to `auto` for the specific element, or overriding it to a different value.