# padding is getting added to width of div

Tags: html, css

i use this code

```
<div class="main">
<div class="babyOne">
</div>
<div class="babyTwo">
</div>
</div>

.main{
width:100%;
position:relative;
}
.babyOne,.badyTwo{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

with this CSS above everything works fine.

but as soon as i give padding to inner divs all the ui breaks,

```
.babyOne,.badyTwo{
width:50%;
float:left;
padding:5px;
}
```

and fire bug shows the increase in the width of divs equal to padding.
According to padding property this should not happen.
any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Simply use `box-sizing:border-box;`

That will add padding and borders within the original width of the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to learn CSS `box-model`

[image]

This states that whatever `padding, border, margin` you add to you element does count outside it, so for example the element is of `200px width` and `100px height`, if you add `padding` say `5px` than the `width` and `height` will be `205px` and `105px` respectively, so inorder to workaround with this you need to use CSS3 `box-sizing` property, but as still it is `CSS3` property and if IE is the main thing you want to supprt, I suggest you to resize the elements according to your needs

So for example a div with these styles

```
div {
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

You can re-size the above as

```
div {
   height: 95px;
   width: 195px;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

CSS3 `box-sizing` [Reference](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. you are also pointing to the question that padding should not change the width of box. anyway i got my answer. in these cases one should not use width in %, use absolute values like 400px.

Answer (score 1):

The WRAPPER must have fixed size: http://jsfiddle.net/esVgH/1 example:

```
.main{
   width:200px;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Ya, this worked. This is strange. in my case main has 980px. when i and if give width of 50% to divs without padding both take 490px. if i add 5px padding both have width equal to 500px.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the expected behaviour.
You set a width and then you say give it some padding.
So the width plus the padding is going to be greater than the original width.

You can try CSS3s `box-sizing` attribute: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

I'm not sure how widely supported it is though.

There's also a host of SO answers here: [How apply padding in HTML without increasing the div size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162476/how-apply-padding-in-html-without-increasing-the-div-size)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is display the .baby as a table cell:

```
.babyOne, .badyTwo {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.babyOne,.badyTwo{

width:45%; /* As you have like based on padding */

float:left;

padding:5px;

}

Comment: Thanks for quick response.i know this.my question is why padding changing the width of div? If i am right it should not.Margin will change that.